# Set Output Cache attribute regarding to condition ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, outputcache

i am using output cache attribute to cache my page ,

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 50000)]
    public ActionResult GetRidOfZombies()
    {
       // Code 
    }
```

now the problem is that i have two domain running the same application `abc.com` and `xyz.com`
i want to do that when any user see my site in `xyz.com` then this cache attribute trim down to `[OutputCache(Duration = 50)]` .... How should i do that . I searched it alot on google but didn't find any solution . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom attribute:

```
public class MyDomainAwareOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // TODO: extract the domain from filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
        // and set the duration accordingly

        Duration = 50000;

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[MyDomainAwareOutputCache]
public ActionResult GetRidOfZombies()
{
    // Code 
}
```